# Although it's commonly known as _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ , it's also called

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer consists of three words.

---

[image: A series of squares - some fully coloured, others with only a central stripe coloured - and a 5x5 grid of letters titled with 'count from left-to-right, top-to-bottom']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> SOLIDS AND STRIPES

The logic:

> The colored blocks in the question are the colors of [billiard balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-ball#Equipment) (indeed, the title blanks out the term BILLIARDS, though the game with these colors is more formally called "pocket billiards", and less formally "pool"), with some blocks "stripes" and some "solid".  Translating the colors to numbers yields:
>
>  2,9,6,15,1,10,3,8,14,7,11,5,12,4,13

Counting as stated:

> Starting from the beginning for each letter, we have the initial S from the picture, and then the grid yields the remainder of the message: SOLIDS AND STRIPES.

Comment: Aren't those three words? :)

Comment: OP may have intended the particular form of your answer that's named after the final, black target: that fits the topic a bit better, being an actual synonym for the three words you found.

Comment: Oops, I intended to have "rvtug onyy" originally, then I switched to the answer you just found, but forgot to change to "*three* words". Well done anyways.